# How to find what map task ran on what datanode?

Tags: hadoop

I ran a hadoop job which has 32 maps and no reduce. 4 of them constantly fail. I guess they all are running on the same datanode. I have a total of 6 datanode. How do I find what map ran on what datanode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Job Tracker UI at port 50030 and you will find logs for each task which shows where that task (map task/reduce task) ran

Comment: I have been using cloudera interface which has been missing lot of information. port 50030 is very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Namenode page on browser. and click on live nodes. You will get link for each node separately. Click on this link and u will get the logs for map and reduce tasks separately. You can see what the problem is.